# What are some ways to pass raw bytes to a program via the Linux terminal?

Tags: binary-analysis, binary, fuzzing

I want to pass raw bytes to a (C) program using the Linux Bash shell. I find that when I try to pass for example "\x00\xFF\xAB", the program receiving the input actually gets the **ASCII character codes** for the string, rather than interpret them as the raw bytes.

One way I've seen people accomplish this is by calling `python -c 'print("\x00\xFF\xAB")'` and piping output to the program under test. Is there a way to do this without using Python by just using the Bash shell?

Comment: You can use ‘printf \xbb’, where you replace ‘bb’ by the byte you want. The only problem is, you cannot pass null byte this way.

Comment: Ah thanks do you know how I could pass a null byte?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't. :/

Comment: @bart1e thanks I don't think there is a way to do it like this. For null bytes I may have to run execve manually and pass the args I believe.

Comment: @bart1e: you can print NUL bytes with printf. You just can't save them in a variable.

Comment: Arguments are null-terminated strings; you can't include a null byte in an argument. You can only read them from a file (such as standard input).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `echo -e` and pipe to your program's input.

Example:
`echo -e "\x41\x42\x43\x44" | <executable>`
Will write ABCD as input.

edit:
You can pass null-bytes

Comment: would you mind adding an example on how to pass bytes as an *argument* to the executable?

Comment: Put the `echo -e` command after the executable name, surrounded by backticks: (`).
Null bytes are ok in this method too. (Newline chars, however, will break the string)

Comment: @Yotamz yikes ... backticks? That's so 1990s. Drop the backticks and use `$(...)` to dodge the escaping nightmare that ensues as soon as you start nesting backticks ... null bytes will work in arguments? I find that surprising, since they're treated as zero-terminated. Can you substantiate that claim?

Comment: Yes, tried it with `ls`, echo -e "\x2E\x2E" (ls ..) works the same as `ls` with echo "\x2E\x00\x2E", even though it supposedly ends the string. I'd expect the latter to be treated as just "\x2E" and list the current folder but it doesn't. I agree with you on the backticks-escaping though.

Answer (score 18):

If you need null bytes, you can write them to a file and use the file as input for the program, e.g.:

> echo -e -n "\x00\xFF\xAB" > file.bin
>
> program < file.bin

You can use also use [`xxd`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xxd) to convert hex to binary:

> echo "00 FF AB" | xxd -r -p | program

Comment: Upvoted for the use of `xxd` – it is much more convenient without the backslashes.